# "out" and "in" characters broken in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, character, out

**Hey guys,**

Recently I installed Eclipse (Neon 4.6.3) on my Ubuntu (16.04) GNOME OS and ran into some problems, like special characters breaking on originally Windows 8 workspaces and GTK3 Gnome interface problems (had to force it to initiate on GTK2). But still got a minimal and quite annoying bug that I couldn't find any kind of fix nor workarounds, didn't find any infos about that on the web either. The "out" and "in" from System seems to be broken somehow, they appear as characters that doesn't exists when I put it after "System.", right as it gets formatted by Eclipse. Does anyone have any idea of where this is coming from?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa68q.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpeQR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default settings Eclipse will render static methods and fields with italic characters.  It might be a font problem on your system.  You can change the configuration under `Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring`.  Turn off the syntax highlighting for statics there.

Comment: That seems to be the solution, Maybe pick another font.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much guys!